# Maven: How do I skip install/deploy of quickstart or example modules during a build and releases?

Tags: maven

My project structure looks like this:

```
 foo
   - foo-core
   - foo-integration
     - foo-quarkus-extension
     - foo-spring-boot-starter
   - foo-quickstarts
     - foo-quickstart1
     - foo-quickstart2
```

Those modules `foo-quickstart1` and `foo-quickstart2` are a bit special:

1. They are both in the `<modules>` element of `foo-quickstarts`, to ensure an IDE (such as IntelliJ) autoconfigures them
2. They get included in the distribution zip as is, for new users to copy paste.
3. They don't have any parent pom (so they don't extend `foo-quickstarts` nor `foo`).
4. They use version `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and that never changes. All other modules use version `7.38.0-SNAPSHOT` and release every 3 weeks.

**How do I avoid that `foo-quickstart1` and `foo-quickstart2` end up in the local/remote maven repository - especially during releases?** I still want them to compile and test when I do `mvn clean install` of `foo`.

Comment: And you probably don't want to add entries to the POMs of `foo-quickstart1` and `foo-quickstart2`, right?

Comment: yes, indeed, as users starting from one of those quickstarts, don't need them.

Comment: You could think about using Maven archetypes instead of copy/paste quickstart projects.

Comment: The quickstarts should work with `git clone`and then `mvn clean install`. Archetypes are a pain in my experience.

Comment: I manage some archetypes, and it works well.

Comment: Yea, but I can't convince most users to actually use them. They just want to git clone and build.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see without littering the POMs of the quickstart projects is to either:

- Split your multi-module project into two (which you probably don't want).
- Split the build process by using the `-pl` parameter to build only parts of the multi-module project in one go.

Usually, I would have added `skip` parameters to the maven install and maven deploy plugin in the relevant projects, but this is not an option here.

Comment: Interesting, but indeed neither works for me. I don't want to have to teach everyone to add `-pl` every time, nor create multiple projects. I was hoping for a `<profile>` approach.